# Why string.TrimEnd not removing only last character in string

Tags: c#, string, trim

I have string as below

```
2,44,AAA,BBB,1,0,,,
```

So now i want to remove only last comma in above string. So i want output as

```
2,44,AAA,BBB,1,0,,
```

I decided to use TrimeEnd as below

```
str.ToString.TrimEnd(',')
```

But it removed all the commas after 0. So i get output as below

```
2,44,AAA,BBB,1,0
```

Why it removes all the 3 commas after 0? I just need to remove last character in string

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Why it removes all the 3 commas after 0?

Because that's what it's [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) to do:

> **Return value:**
>   The string that remains after all occurrences of the characters in the `trimChars` parameter are removed from the end of the current string.

If you only want the final character removed, you could use:

```
if (str.EndsWith(","))
{
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
}
```

Or equivalently:

```
if (str.EndsWith(","))
{
    str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Please don't go removing braces from my code. My personal coding style (and the one which has been enforced in every company I've worked at) is to *always* include braces for loops, `if` statements etc. It avoids problems where the indentation can imply that the code behaves one way, when it actually behaves differently.

Answer (score 5):

That is expected. `String.TrimEnd` Removes **all** trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object

The [`TrimEnd(char[] trimChars)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) method removes from the current string all trailing characters that are in the `trimChars` parameter. **The trim operation stops when the first character that is not in `trimChars` is encountered** at the end of the string

Use this instead:

```
str = str.EndsWith(",") ? str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1) : str;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
string s = "2,44,AAA,BBB,1,0,,,";
s = s.Remove(s.Length-1, 1);
```

Comment: That will remove *any* character, regardless of whether or not it is a comma.

Comment: I don't know whether maybe you misunderstood... suppose the string was: `string s = "2,44,AAA,BBB,1,0,,,123`, what would happen?

Comment: @DannyBeckett It's a legitimate interpretation of the question, IMO. *If* the string is already known to end with a comma, there is no need to check.

Comment: @DannyBeckett-I answered specific to this situation in string. I know its not a universal way to go for but in this case it can be a way

Answer (score 2):

Remember Please, the TrimEnd() is not an inplace function. You should reassign its result to `str`:

```
str = str.TrimEnd(',')
```